# Display Total minus Shipping Cost on Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to echo on cart a number:
Total - Coupon - Shipping

```
$first_number = $woocommerce->cart->total;
$second_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_shipping_total;
$sum_total = $first_number - $second_number;
echo $sum_total;
```

and got this error: WARNING: A NON-NUMERIC VALUE ENCOUNTERED.

**UPDATE**

I get the cart total and remove the shipping cost. Now is working perfectly!

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->total;
$current_shipping_method_cost = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_total();
$sum_total = (float)$cart_total - (float)$current_shipping_method_cost;
```

Comment: Thanks my solution help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we got issue is one line $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_shipping_total;

"get_cart_shipping_total" return formatted shipping with a currency symbol(eg $5.00), that's why subtraction operation return error.

you should replace

$second_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_shipping_total

to

$second_number = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_total();

Full working code is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'woo_update_subtotal' );  
function woo_update_subtotal() {

   $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;
   $current_shipping_method_cost = WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();

   $sum_total = (float)$cart_subtotal - (float)$current_shipping_method_cost;
WC()->cart->set_subtotal($sum_total);

   return $sum_total;
}
```

==========================

OR

==========================

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'woo_update_subtotal' );  
function woo_update_subtotal() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart_subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->subtotal;
    $current_shipping_method_cost = $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_total();
    
    $sum_total = (float)$cart_subtotal - (float)$current_shipping_method_cost;
    $woocommerce->cart->set_subtotal($sum_total);

    return $sum_total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me to found a solution, but the code output wrong price i dont know the reason.

Comment: As I am testing on my wp site its return current price without any issue

Comment: First you check $cart_subtotal and $current_shipping_method_cost. you getting correct or not like echo $current_shipping_method_cost.